# Java8 streams : Transpose map with values as list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have map with key as String and value as List. List can have 10 unique values. I need to convert this map with key as Integer and value as List. Example as below :

**Input :**

"Key-1" : 1,2,3,4

"Key-2" : 2,3,4,5

"Key-3" : 3,4,5,1

**Expected output :**

1 : "Key-1","Key-3"

2 : "Key-1","Key-2"

3 : "Key-1", "Key-2", "Key-3"

4 : "Key-1", "Key-2", "Key-3"

5 : "Key-2", "Key-3"

I am aware that using for loops i can achieve this but i needed to know can this be done via streams/lamda in java8.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

An idea could be to generate all value-key pairs from the original map and then group the keys by these values:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

...

Map<Integer, List<String>> transposeMap =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(i, e.getKey())))
       .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

Answer (score 4):

[Alexis’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38475538/2711488) contains the general solution for this kind of task, using `flatMap` and a temporary holder for the combination of key and flattened value. The only alternative avoiding the creation of the temporary holder objects, is to re-implement the logic of the `groupingBy` collector and inserting the *loop over the value list* logic into the accumulator function:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapT = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (m,e) -> e.getValue().forEach(
                 i -> m.computeIfAbsent(i,x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(e.getKey())),
    (m1,m2) -> m2.forEach((k,v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2); return l1;})));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit scary (I generally try to break it down to make it more readable) but you could do it this way:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> transposeMap = new HashMap<>();

map.forEach((key, list) -> list.stream().forEach(
    elm -> transposeMap.put(elm,
        transposeMap.get(elm) == null ? Arrays.asList(key) : (Stream.concat(transposeMap.get(elm).stream(),
            Arrays.asList(key).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())))));
```

Assuming `Map<String, List<Integer>> map` is your original Map that you want to transpose. `transposeMap` will have transposed map that you need.

Comment: Streams are better suited for stateless operations. While this answer is correct, it would be better suited to an imperative style. It's basically the OP's loop strategy, but relabeled with a stream's `forEach` instead.

Comment: `forEach` does not belong to `stream`s. It is declared in `Iterable`, `list.stream().forEach` should be `list.forEach`.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: Streams also have a `forEach` method, though with a slightly different semantic.

Comment: @Holger I know that, but I've always tought the point of having forEach in a `stream` is to gain some *potential* performance(parralelism) after a long pipeline where you are already streamed. Is there actually a point of *streaming* a `Collection` if all you want to do is loop over it ? (I don't think so)

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: there’s no point in using this more complicated variant (besides testing), but that’s a different statement than “should be [the simpler form]”.

Answer (score 2):

You can Achieve in this way

Let suppose I have Person class with Gender and Age . I want to get it in this form

```
Map<SEX,List<Person>>
```

I would write simply

```
Map<SEX,List<Person>> map =  personList.stream()

                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```

it will get me something like below (one key against multiple values )

```
key:MALE
age31sexMALE
age28sexMALE

key:FEMALE
age40sexFEMALE
age44sexFEMALE
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since you are assuming you have one big List<Person> as an input with elements having gender field. Translating OP's question into your example, OP has `Map<Person,List<SEX>>` .

Answer (score 0):

*with* `teeing` *You can work on keys and values in 2 streams separately*
since Java 12

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> to = from.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(teeing(flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), toList()),
      flatMapping(e -> (Stream<String>)e.getValue().stream().map(i -> e.getKey()), toList()),
      (k, v) -> {
        return IntStream.range(0, k.size()).boxed().collect(
            groupingBy(i -> k.get(i), mapping(i -> v.get(i), toList())));
      }));
```