# Java stream reverse a multimap

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Concept: two types `A` and `B`, each may map to multiple elements of the other type.

Suppose I have an input list: `List<A> aList`, how to generate a map `Map<B, List<A>> result` with Java 8 stream?

```
Map<B, List<A>> result = aList.stream().flatMap(a -> a.getBs().stream().map(b -> new Tuple2<>(b, a)) // just create pairs of (B, A) for each a
                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(???)); // then group these pairs by b
```

Or would Guava or Apache Comms provide such functionality?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Tukani, please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471056/) for answer.

Comment: Can you post your Tuple2 class? As a hint, you need to group by the first field of your tuple, and as downstream, map the tuple to its second field and collect it into a list. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471056/java8-streams-transpose-map-with-values-as-list/

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki, that worked for me!